# Cannot access CloudBees WebDAV at all

Tags: webdav, cloudbees

Using Mac (Mountain Lion) to attempt to connect to my CloudBees WebDAV repository, using my account name (drcadmin) using the server address "https://repository-drcadmin.forge.cloudbees.com/private/"

When I'm challenged to enter my account user name and password, I'm getting an error message: "There was a problem connecting to the server 'repository-drcadmin.forge.cloudbees.com'. \ Check the server name or IP address, and then try again. If you continue to have problems, contact your system administrator.". I'm just having no luck at all connecting to our private WebDAV repo. My understanding is that this *should* work... but it doesn't.

I currently have a Free account -- do I need a paid account to get this feature "turned on"? Or am I just doing something wrong? (And if I am doing something wrong, any clue what I would eed to do to fix it?)

Comment: Solution: the instructions on the CloudBees site regarding the URL are wrong. The instructions state that the URL is "https://repository-{accountId}.forge.cloudbees.com/private/". In fact the URL *should* be "https://repository-{account-domain-name}.forge.cloudbees.com/private/". That is, use the domain name, not the account ID.

Comment: The "account ID" and the "domain name" are the same thing - they're probably used a little too interchangeably in the documentation however. I'm not sure what the difference you're seeing between the two is - and we do want to improve any documentation that is confusing.

Comment: Actually I worked out what you mean - your interpretation of account ID is what we call username internally - a soon to be deprecated concept. I will find the documentation and update it to make it clearer.

Comment: @user1818557 you can reply to your own question (and accept your own answer) if you think you have it figured out.

Comment: @Ben is this the page here: http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Mounting+DAV+Repositories ?

Comment: @MichaelNeale - This one http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/CloudBees+Maven+Repository+-+Mounting

Answer (score 0):

No it works with free.

The canonical article on how to set this up is here: http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/CloudBees+Maven+Repository+-+Mounting

Answer (score 0):

I found these links to be helpful:

- http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Accessing+under+an+external+Maven+repository
- http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Sharing+Files+with+Build+Executors

Specifically:

1. Check that you can access `Repositories > Maven repositories > Private` - https://forge.cloudbees.com/a/{yourid}/repositories/private
2. Check the config under `Details` and `Security` are correct.